# Laravel blade debug view name on error

Tags: debugging, laravel, view, laravel-blade

when there is some error in view, L4 shows a nice trace, but cached filename:
open: /var/www/webpage/app/storage/views/1154ef6ad153694fd0dbc90f28999013

howto during view-rendering-to-cache save view's path/name (in a comment or something)?
Or better yet - to show it in the debug-error-page (its called whoops or something?)

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to tackle this problem is add a `html` comments (not `blade` ones as they will not be rendered in compiled view) in sections which get echoed.

```
@section('content)

<!-- FILE: app/views/main/index.blade.php -->

<Your Content Goes Here>

@stop
```

This html comment will get rendered in the compiled source of the view. Of course you will have to inspect the compiled view first to identify which view is the problematic one. But in my experience, this method work almost all the time.

Comment: Well, that is a quick workaround that is just fine for me, thanks =)

Comment: I would however wrap it in something like `@if(env('APP_DEBUG') == 1) <!-- comment --> @endif `. Even though the filename is not sensitive information, It's a good practice to not leak any debug info to end users.

Comment: I agree with @Fx32.

Comment: `<!-- {{ __FILE__ }} -->` shows the compiled filename, not the source

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to de encrypt view names , but one method i do is to

```
{{dd('will you reach here ')}}
```

Trying to move this line from view to another to watch where php render reach .

I know it is not the right way  nor the professional one , but it may help in some cases .

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly a problema, this is a compiled version of your view.

Laravel Blade System will compile all your views and subviews into a single file and, if you didn't change anything on them it will always try to use the compiled version, to speed up your system.

Sometimes is hard to know wich one of our views is related to that error. Using Sublime text, what I do is to hit CTRL-P (windows) and paste the number of the compiled view (1154ef6ad153694fd0dbc90f28999013) and it will bring it to me right away.

Of course, you won't do any changes on it. This is just way to find the view you have problems in, so you can then find the real file and fix it. If you know wich file is the problematic one, you don't have to do this, go directly to your file.

Comment: This is a little problema as i dont need the compiled view that you can bring with CTRL-P, you do fixes in the original view file

Comment: You won't do any changes on it. This is just way to find the view you have problems in, so you can then find the real file and fix it. If you know wich file is the problematic one, you don't have to do this, go directly to your file.

Comment: did you understand that there is no simple way to find the original view file? I need to search for file that has similar text, with something like: find . -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "some_file_content"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The line number corresponds to the compiled view, not the blade template.

Answer (score 2):

I created a helper that checks to see if you are working locally or in development mode, It then outputs an HTML comment.

```
{{ printViewComment('mockup/reports@content') }}

<!-- Template: mockup/reports@content -->
```

I chose to name the comments like this *path.file_name@yeild_name* but I only wish this was an automated featured.

Comment: thanks. there is more annoying problem, when there is an error in view eval, we get a blank page instead of pointer to the line with error...

Comment: Very nice use of a helper function for this! Btw; if you do not want to display this information in production, you could wrap your comment in something like: `@if (config('app.env') !== 'production')`

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer after looking into source,
when on the Whoops! page, just look for render in the sidebar, there will be the name of the view file...