# How do I disable Laravel view cache?

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an exception in one of my views. However, instead of telling me the name of the view so I can find it and fix it, laravel says it is in `app/storage/views/110a3ecc0aa5ab7e6f7f50ef35a67a8b`, which is meaningless.

How do I disable this view caching, so that laravel uses and refers to the actual files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel and view caching in development -- can't see changes right away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579182/laravel-and-view-caching-in-development-cant-see-changes-right-away)

Comment: @RobbieP that question refers to php caching, and is a completely separate issue. My question is specifically about laravel's built-in view caching system, and is not a duplicate.

Comment: I must have misread your question. Laravel needs to compile your blade files before they get rendered, so I'm not sure you will be able to see which named view the error occurs in, but you can open the compiled view. See @Antonio's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866546/942846

Answer (score 26):

Out of the box? You can't. But you can extend the BladeCompiler class, overriding the method resposible for checking if the view has been expired:

```
class MyBladeCompiler extends BladeCompiler {

    public function isExpired($path)
    {
        if ( ! \Config::get('view.cache'))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return parent::isExpired($path);
    }

}
```

You'll need to replace the BladeCompiler instance in IoC container, with your own compiler:

```
$app = App::make('app'); // or just $app = app();

$app->bindShared('blade.compiler', function($app)
{
    $cache = $app['path.storage'].'/views';

    return new MyBladeCompiler($app['files'], $cache);
});
```

And then you just need to create that key in your app/config/view.php file

```
<?php

return [

    'cache' => false,

    'paths' => [base_path().'/resources/views'],

    'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',

];
```

Or, like I do here:

```
return [

    'cache' => in_array(App::environment(), ['production', 'staging']),

];
```

Comment: Where may I put the second portion of code? In the AppServiceProvider?

Comment: I tried to add in AppServiceProvider, but it doesn't call isExpired method. Also bindShared is renamed to singleton in 5.5

Comment: AppServiceProvider didn't work for me, either. The binding was overwritten by the core ViewServiceProvider. I overcame this by extending ViewServiceProvider with a custom class with a new registerBladeEngine() method, and replaced the core ViewServiceProvider with my custom class in the providers array in config/app.php

Comment: Latest version of laravel support this by default, check below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71790040/8485567

Answer (score 14):

this worked for me...  added this to the .env file

```
CACHE_EXPIRE=-1
```

Comment: This does a lot more than disable view caching. That's worth mentioning. -1

Answer (score 14):

In laravel > v9.7.0, you can add inside `config/view.php`:

```php
'cache' => App::environment('local') ? false : true
```

Here is the PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/41859

Comment: Get to the top! ☝️ Thanks for answering here, and for the PR, of course. 

Comment: this is not working in laravel10

Comment: I didn't need the environment check since my app only has one view  - it's a Laravel/Inertia/React SPA stack.  No need for a view cache that I can see.  I just set 'cache' => false

Comment: @Nate_F I suppose its still working for you on laravel10? I ask because of the comment of user151496

Comment: @BernardWiesner Yes.  I think his problem is that he needs to use config('app.env') instead of App::environment.  In my case I'm not making a call to environment, but if I did I would use config('app.env').  Thanks Bernard.

Comment: @BernardWiesner In other words, your code should look like this for Laravel 10.
'cache' => config('app.env') == 'local' ? false : true

Answer (score 6):

Solution

open php.ini

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=0
```

change to this. restart apache.

Comment: How does this relate to laravel?

Comment: Then probably your problem was not laravel caching, but php caching - these settings relate to the php opcache, which is a different thing from the laravel view cache.

Answer (score 4):

check your .env file 
Change CACHE_DRIVER=file to CACHE_DRIVER=array

Answer (score 3):

If you have `artisan`, it's easy to clear the cache

```
php artisan view:clear
```

If you don't have or don't want `artisan` (can't think why you wouldn't want it, it's very useful), you can from the root of your project do

```
cd storage/framework/views/
rm *.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cache in this way, as well:

```
// Clear cache in laravel
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    // return what you want
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full answer

Go to vendor/illuminate/BladeCompiler.php
change these 2 lines

**use Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler;
class BladeCompiler extends Compiler implements CompilerInterface**

with the following:

**use App\Support\CustomCompiler;
class BladeCompiler extends CustomCompiler implements CompilerInterface**

in your app/support folder (or whatever structure you are using)
create the following class

namespace App\Support;

```
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler;

class CustomCompiler extends Compiler {

    public function isExpired($path) {

        if ( !\config('blade.use_cache')) 
               return true;

        return parent::isExpired($path);
    }
}
```

your blade config file will look like this

```
return [
    'use_cache' => false,
    'cache' => storage_path('cache'),
    'views' => resources_path('views')
];
```

auto dump and run....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP, disable OPCache under Preferences, General, PHP-Cahce. just select off. thank me later.

Answer (score -1):

Although some would call this sketchy, this was the quickest and most minimal way to do this on a small application I was working on

On the controller(s) that my routes pointed to:

```
public function __construct()
{
    exec('php /full/path/to/artisan view:clear');
}
```

Comment: I would advise against this approach if performance and scalability are important goals of your project.

Comment: I'd advise against ever using `exec` at all tbh.. but if you're desperate :)

Comment: You can now use the `Artisan` facade to avoid using `exec`: `Artisan::call('view:clear')`

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Creates view cache file because it has been told to do that. In `.env` File you will come across `cache_driver` which has default property as `file` change it to `array`.

Comment: Please post an example snippet of the .env file.

Comment: The cache_driver property controls exactly what it says - driver used for cache. One should not ruin all cache like Redis to disable only the view cache

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the party, however.
I had the same issue: the browser not reflecting changes to the php code.

Simple solution for me was:

set the clock on the server to the same time as the dev computer !

```
sudo date +%T -s "11:14:00"
```

Answer (score -2):

In development environment, I just add and modify the next:

- `bootstrap/start.php`

  ```
  $env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){return 'testing';});
  ```
- `app/config/testing/cache.php` add in array

  ```
  'cache' => false,
  ```
- `app/config/view.php` add in array

  ```
  'cache' => false,
  ```

Comment: Does not work. This may be due to laravel version - I am using 4.1 currently; was this changed in a later version?