# What is the best way to clear or reset Laravel cached views?

Tags: php, laravel

Sometimes my changes are not reflected in the output even after i have modified the view that generates the output. What is the best way to clear the view cache or particular cached view?

Comment: You might find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813251/how-do-i-disable-laravel-view-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `artisan` command

```
$ php artisan cache:clear
```

to clear the `cache`