# Laravel session bug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-session

Why is that even though I forget a session already it stills prints its value when I press back button ?
Is this kind of a bug in laravel or am i doing something wrong with my code ?

here is how i forget the session

```
session()->forget('user_role');
session()->forget('user_id');
```

but even if i do that it still prints the value in the console when I press the back button.
I've tried other methods already , such as the pull method and reassigning new values but the problem still exists.

Comment: If you refresh does it update to the expected value? Could it be a local caching issue?

Comment: Because the session is stored in a cookie, and that cookie is cached.

Comment: @Joe The cookie only stores the session id, not any actual value.

Comment: @DanLewis after refreshing it updates to the expected value .

Comment: @Joe What in the world does "the cookie is cached" mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers to learn more about controlling the browser cache

Comment: Have you tried the `regenerate()` method of session. This should generate new session identifier, thus invalidating the old identifier.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin ive tried that already also the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The **`session()->forget('user_role')`** is performing well. However, You are still able to view/print because browser has cached that page and instead of making a network call, request just heats the cache.

To identify and disable cached for a while, Open up the dev tools and disable cache while dev tool is open and refresh the page. After that, you'll no longer be able to see that data stored in the session key. For your reference, The page you are seeing is browser cached one. 
This is the temporary solution if you want to check the value being washed or not. However, if you don't want your user to have this behavior, You can try given solutions.

For the browser-based cache control, you should try setting the `Cache-Control`, `Pragma` and `Expires` header with your page response as given,

```php
$contents = View::make('viewname');
return response($contents)-> withHeaders([
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'Expires' => 0
]);
```

this will allow you to control the page being cached in browser. Setting the `Expires` to 0 means the page never gonna be cached. You can refer the [Official MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) here.

You should also try [disabling the Laravel blade view cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813251/how-do-i-disable-laravel-view-cache) if the problem still persists or other solution doesn't give satisfactory outcome.

Comment: That's obviously not a permanent solution, since you can't ask your users to run with dev tools open…

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the browser cached page from showing ? and also when I press back doesn't it call my controller again ? I am just used to asp.net mvc where if you press the back button it calls the controller that you've used again and validates the session.

Comment: It's not a permanent solution, but we have to disable that if we are developing that. Otherwise, there is no workaround for this. The browser will cache the page every time.

Comment: @Kabergrammer see the updated answer, to disable the view cache. post a comment if the issue still persists.

Comment: Disabling the *internal* cache won't help. You need to set **appropriate HTTP headers** to prevent the browser from caching pages.

Comment: @KiranManiya thanks for the answers but i think the solutions not for permanent usage and the disabling of view cache might affect other functions that I have .

Comment: @deceze can you share on how to appropriately set HTTP headers ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Comment: @deceze You are right, I was just updating my answer :-)