# Get original path and filename of hashed name in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel application in production server that produces exception when rendering the view. The log file printed stacktraces about where the exception happened, but with hashed name of view.

How do I get the original path and the filename of hashed view? Since I can only debug from the error log in the server. For example with this stacktrace, I want to find the original file path and name of 698a6499f344ea0485830fd76f437b7ae1833431.php

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$balance_perdana in /var/app/current/storage/framework/views/698a6499f344ea0485830fd76f437b7ae1833431.php:44
Stack trace:
#0 /var/app/current/storage/framework/views/698a6499f344ea0485830fd76f437b7ae1833431.php(44): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/var/app/curren...', 44, Array)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(42): include('/var/app/curren...')
```

There are solution that uses laravel debugbar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to help find the related view, but I think this is not a good practice, activate debug mode in production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel stores compiled version file to speed up system execution.

Once your file is compiled and if you do not make changes into it then laravel direct executes this compiled version and this is how laravel executes fast process work.

So, displaying original name of file is not feasible.

Now for the solution, you can comment out your blade file name with `<!-- BLADEFILENAME-->` into particular file. So while facing any error then you can understand that which file is this.

Review Reference: [Laravel blade debug view name on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866123/laravel-blade-debug-view-name-on-error/23775400#23775400)

Comment: Thanks, but still I'm curious if there is another way to get the filename without adding comment manually in each file

Comment: Ok, I'll review for it and will provide you workaround.

Comment: Yes, You can try same option like  `<!-- {{ __FILE__ }} -->` in master.blade.php file.

Comment: `<!-- {{ __FILE__ }} -->` shows the compiled filename, not the source

Comment: @PaulH https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022521/470749 shows how to get view name in Laravel Blade.